# Is a Mersenne prime always of the form $4n + 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is a Mersenne prime always of the form $4n + 3$?

Examples:

> $M_3 = 7 = 4 \times 1 + 3$
>
> $M_5 = 31 = 4 \times 7 + 3$
>
> $M_7 = 127 = 4 \times 31 + 3$
>
> $M_{13} = 8191 = 4 \times 2047 + 3$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since $n \ge 2, 2^n-1 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @Jerry, and this shows that $2^n-1$ does not even have to be prime.

Comment: Thanks a lot to Sandeep and Nicky